# Laravel crashes when calling object method within config file

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, config

I faced the issue (laravel crashes) when I trying to call object method (or static method) within config file. I use it to cache all formatted product prices in one place. Please suggest how can I solve this issue? Please find the code below:

**app\routes.php:**

```
Route::get('test', function() {
    dd(Config::get('settings.productPrices'));
});
```

**app\config\settings.php:**

```
$setting_data['productPrices'] = Cache::remember('settings.productPrices', 60, function()
{
    $products = Product::all();
    $prices = [];
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $prices [$product->id] = $product->getPriceFormatted();
    }
    return $prices;
});
return $setting_data;
```

getPriceFormatted method works fine. If I use $product->price instead of $product->getPriceFormatted() everything works fine.

**app\models\Product.php:**

```
public function getPriceFormatted () {

    if (Config::has('settings.exchangeRateUsdToUah')) {
        return Config::get('settings.exchangeRateUsdToUah') * $this->price. ' UAH';
    }
    return $this->price . ' USD';
}
```

P.S. Config::get('settings.exchangeRateUsdToUah') works fine.

Comment: You're going to need to tell us how exactly it 'crashes', like, what error/exception do you see? Without that, no one would be able to identify what's going on.

Comment: page infinitely loads. and other site pages don't respond as well. even after pc rebooting any page doesn't work.

Comment: "doesn't work" is the least descriptive thing ever

Comment: i.e. all pages infinitely load without any return

Answer (score 0):

The config is loaded before Laravel is completely set up, thus I cannot use most of its parts at this point.